# JOIN with the last id

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery, query-performance

I want to select a record from one table (`customers` table) and join only with the last from other related table (`sales` table). I know two ways of doing it, but I don't know which one have better performance. What is the best approach?

Note: in my case I'll get only one row because I want the data for one specific customer but what if I want all the main rows, does it change something?

Option 1, using sub-query in WHERE:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, s.id, s.cost
FROM
  customers as c
  LEFT JOIN sales as s ON s.customer_id = c.id
WHERE
  c.id = 42
  AND s.id = (SELECT MAX(s2.id) FROM sales as s2 WHERE s2.customer_id = c.id) ;
```

Option 2, using sub-query in FROM:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, s.id, s.cost
FROM
  customers as c
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s2.customer_id as cid, MAX(s2.id) as maxid 
    FROM sales as s2 
    WHERE s2.customer_id = 42 
    GROUP BY s2.customer_id
  ) maxids ON c.id = maxids.cid
  LEFT JOIN sales as s ON s.id = maxids.maxid
WHERE
  c.id = 42 ;
```

---

Here are the tables `CREATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22149 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_c

CREATE TABLE `sales` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `buydate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `cost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `customer_key` (`customer_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `status_key` (`status`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `sales_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11555 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
```

And here their EXPLAINS:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY c   NULL    const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  NULL
1   PRIMARY s   NULL    const   PRIMARY,customer_key    PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  NULL
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Select tables optimized away

id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY c   NULL    const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  NULL
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   100.00  NULL
1   PRIMARY s   NULL    const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  NULL
DERIVED s2  NULL    ref customer_key    customer_key    5   const   11  100.00
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the `AND s.id = (SELECT MAX(s2.id) FROM sales as s2 WHERE s2.customer_id = c.id)` from the 2nd query. Also, the 2nd query doesn't seem valid syntax. That `WHERE s2.customer_id = c.id` should not be there, inside the subquery and there should be a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Did you try profiling the two queries?

Comment: The general case (all customers instead of one) is a [_Groupwise Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) problem.  Optimizing the one-customer case will not be helpful the general case.

Comment: @Erik No, I'm not very good at profiling and getting useful conclusions beyond this one is faster but I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, I forgot to remove it. I though `where` is valid but I was wrong because in my real consult I was using the literal '42' not c.id.

Comment: @Erik I have made a profile of both queries and the result is more or less the same but in my heart I feel they shouldn't be the same.

Comment: For both of the proposed queries, `INDEX(customer_id, id)` is useful.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames I have added SHOW CREATE and EXPLAN.

Comment: I've modified your 2nd query, so it's easily adjustable for the general case (just remove the internal WHERE and modify or remove the external one.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes find this technique useful for judging the performance of a query, or for comparing two possible queries.  It is especially helpful before the table is large enough to get reliable timings.

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ... ;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

That will give a few counters.  If I see numbers that are about equal to the number of rows in a table I am selecting from, then I know there was a table scan.  Numbers near the resultset size tend to be more beneficial.  `Handler...write...` indicates that a temp table needed to be generated, and the number says how big it was.

Even without understanding what the numbers represent, it is often 'obvious' which of two `SELECTs` is better.